Commutative Property with More than Two Terms
Suppose I have the expression:
a+b+c+d+e
If I wanted to change the positions of a and e, is this one application of the commutative property of addition, where I can swap these terms directly, or would I need to apply successive applications by only changing the positions of adjacent terms? A similar example is included in Lang's basic mathematics and the solution shows successive applications. Based on the premise of the axiom, it seems the successive steps are not necessary but, surprisingly, none of the textbooks I looked at addresses my question.

Does it matter?

The punchline is that whether commutativity is written to specifically address the case of exactly two addends and this along with associativity implies the general property of commutativity in the sense of rearranging any terms in a sum of $n$ addends... or if it were written where commutativity were defined more generally for $n$ addends which implies the special case of two addends... in the end you have the property you want, allowing you to change the $a$ and the $e$, and merely one definition which allowed for this.  In practice we rarely if ever show such mundane details and just do it.

Thanks for the responses. I agree that, in practice, a lot of steps are not shown and, instead, are done mentally. However, I want to know, from a logical perspective, what is the correct way to apply the property.

The first time, and the first time only, go ahead and go through all of the steps of parenthesizing and swapping things only between adjacent terms... using associativity to get things bracketed in the appropriate way to make the next swap... but once you prove this works (with induction) you should never again need to go through such tedium.  It is a waste of your time and your readers' time.  I will warn you though, that this "stronger commutativity" (if you insist on calling it something different, I don't) still only applies to sums of finitely many numbers, not infinitely many.

No, there are a lot of applications of associativity lurking within. Consider
\begin{align*}
a+b+c&=a+(b+c)=a+(c+b)=(a+c)+b \\
&=(c+a)+b=c+(a+b) \\
&=c+(b+a) .
\end{align*}
So even for only three terms there are two applications of associativity.
In sum, commutativity is about a single operation with exactly two operands.

What is the purpose of grouping terms in the series of steps outlined? This application suggests that it would not be permissible to change the order of an and c in one application. I thought if I did need to apply successive applications, I wouldn't need to involve the associative property. Instead, I would have something like a+b+c = a+c+b = c+a+b = c+b+a

@Jeff00 addition is defined originally as a binary operation, taking exactly one input on the left and one input on the right, and only works as "addition of two things."  $a+b+c$ is not valid notation using the original very restrictive definition of addition, but it is instead shorthand for $(a+b)+c$, or for $a+(b+c)$.  It is after understanding associativity that we can overload the addition symbol to work as an $n$-ary operator... $a+b+c$ being shorthand for "addition of three things" or $a+b+c+d+e$ being "addition of five things."

Addition itself is a binary operation. So, technically, a string like $a+b+c$ is undefined. We have chosen the convention to interpret it as $(a+b)+c$, and since addition is associative, we can get away with simply writing $a+b+c$ because interpreting it as $a+(b+c)$ would give us the same answer anyway.

@Jeff00 in the same way that we can prove commutativity works for arbitrarily large numbers of addends... so too can we prove that associativity works for large numbers of addends, and we can quickly shorthand such long numbers of things being added to not include those parentheses... and can pretend there are parentheses anywhere we want.  $a+b+c+d+e$ can be $(a+(b+c))+(d+e)$ or similar.  As with the question of commutativity on large numbers of things being added, we only bother being this hyper specific with our parenthesis at the start and when defining, but never again after.

Thanks everyone. I understand the points.
